# Horizontal scroll IE8 screen size below 1200px width

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I'm building a Wordpress theme and everything is peachy but I have problem with the layout on IE8 on a screen resolution smaller than 1200px

Basically my layout has 1200px grid width but I figured that there will be a problem with 1024px screen resolution (20% of the population bla bla) so I created media queries when the screen size is smaller than 1199px the grid to change its width to 960px and so on for tablets, phones etc.... and problem solved! EXCEPT!!! for IE8 which does not support media queries and the theme does not resize properly on IE 8 with screen resolution of 1024x768px and ofcourse lower....

So my question is how can I make the design change the grid width to 960px ONLY on IE 8 and lower and screen size bellow 1200px?

Comment: Technically my theme will not work for IE8 users (10% of the world) that have resolution lower then 1200px (23% of the world) that is probably **~2-3%** of the world but still no discrimination based on resolution and terrible browser choices..

Comment: Have you tried using a javascript polyfill ie.. RespondJS https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond ?

Comment: I really prefer css over js.. its cleaner... I solved the problem by adding .ie8 class to the <html> tag if IE8 and simply added .ie8 separate css grid